# Material Design: Change EditText's Color Dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design

This is my material style

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

If I create EditText (or other components) from XML, the color of EditText will use colorControlNormal & colorAccent.

But when I create EditText dynamically, it will not use those colors.
(Become to black)

**How to set the component's style or change the color dynamically ?**

---

**[UPDATE]**

Custom a EditText class also can solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this

```
youreditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: This is what I want! Can you tell me how to change color when component is focused, thank you

Comment: @Ayane.T you can try doing it using onFocusChangeListener.